# Packages already in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages, how can I install it in usr/local/lib/python2.7?

Tags: python, anaconda

I install a packages in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages, how can I install it again in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages?
I use

```
pip install -U nltk
```

but it shows

```
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I am using Mac OsX 10.10.5

Comment: Looks like you need to fix your PATH to point pip back at the local python installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already activated anaconda by including anaconda in environment variable of $PATH and $PYTHONPATH somewhere such as .bashrc depending on your shell.
Just remove or comment that.

With activation,

- $which python
- /home/id/anaconda3/bin/python

Without activation,

- $which python
- /usr/bin/python

Then you can install python package under /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-package/

Comment: Note that if you install using apt-get,it is located at /usr/lib/python$version/dist-package, but using pip, /usr/local/lib/python$version/dist-package